# AS 0.8.14, new project, Fullscreen Activity gives “Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:21.+”

Tags: android-studio, fullscreen, android-gradle-plugin, new-project

For Android Studio 0.8.14 (just downloaded) running on MacOS 10.9.5, brand new project, I get the complaint “Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:21.+” in the Messages Gradle Sync pane.  This happens after I created a new project and in that wizard when doing "Add an activity to Mobile..." I chose "Fullscreen Activity".

If I choose different activities instead of Fullscreen when creating the project, I get different results, some good, some bad.  All the bad results must be linked to the same root problem.  This is What have I done wrong?

I get the same error as above if I instead choose:
Master/Detail Flow Activity
Settings Activity

I get no error if I instead choose:
Blank Activity
Blank Activity with Fragment
Navigation Drawer Activity

I get “Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42
    Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+” when I choose:
Google Maps Activity
Login Activity

I get “Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42" when I choose:
Google Play Services Activity

I get "Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v13:21.+" when I choose:
Tabbed Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which `targetSdkVersion` you select, the template projects may require at least one of the support libraries. You need to install them:

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

> 1. Start the Android SDK Manager.
> 2. In the SDK Manager window, scroll to the end of the Packages list, find the Extras folder and, if necessary, expand to show its contents.
> 3. Select the Android Support Library item. Note: If you're developing with Android Studio, select and install the Android Support Repository
>      item instead.
> 4. Click the Install packages... button.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it.

(Actually, I think the problem was that the SDK I had was left over from trying Android dev via Eclipse.  I thought I'd trashed everything before switching to Android Studio.  I threw out _everything_, downloaded fresh AS, and got the Android SDK Manager to recommend installs.  It included the Support Lib and Repo named in your step 3.  The "new project" wiz now creates a happy FullScreen Activity project.)

I'd upvote you answer, but am a newb here (obv) and so lack reputation.

Comment: @BenChase No worries. Glad you got it resolved. If you click the grey Check mark next to this answer it will mark it as accepted and you will get a little bit of reputation at least.